# Regular language is generated by clear grammar

Tags: regular-languages, finite-automata

Given a regular language , how could we prove that it is alsways ( or can be always ) generated by clear grammar ( such as that for every sentence exists only one derivation tree ).

Could we prove it by creating minimalistic deterministic automata without epsilon transition ?

Comment: "Clear" grammars are usually known as *unambiguous* grammars.

Comment: You seem to have a hunch as to how to answer your question. Have you followed your hunch? Where did you get stuck?